# "Object not set" error

Tags: vba, excel, object

I have a macro in Excel VBA that is giving me an error.  I run it the first time right after I start up Excel and it runs perfectly but when I try to run it any time after that it errors out on the line `nameRow = nameRange.Row` giving the error `Object not set` and I am really confused as to why.

```
Sub AssignGroups()

    Dim membership As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim groups As Worksheet
    Dim nameRow As Long
    Dim fullNameString As String
    Dim nameRange As Range
    Dim groupRange As Range
    Dim nameRange2 As Range
    Dim nameIndex As Long
    Dim userNameString As String
    Dim barIndex As Long



    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set membership = Sheets("User Group Membership")
    Set groups = Sheets("User Assigned to Groups")

    membership.Activate
    Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").Find("user -name")
    nameRow = nameRange.Row
    fullNameString = membership.Cells(nameRow, "A").Value
    nameIndex = InStr(fullNameString, "user -name")
    barIndex = InStr(fullNameString, "|")
    userNameString = Mid(fullNameString, nameIndex + 12, ((barIndex - 4) - (nameIndex + 12)))

    groups.Activate
    Set nameRange2 = groups.Range("A:CH").Find(userNameString)
    nameColumn = nameRange2.Column



    membership.Activate
    membership.Cells(nameRow, "A").Activate

    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate

        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

            cellValue = ActiveCell.Value
            groups.Activate
            Set groupRange = groups.Range("A:CH").Find(cellValue, , , lookat:=xlWhole)
            groupRow = groupRange.Row
            groups.Cells(groupRow, nameColumn).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "X"
            membership.Activate

         End If



        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)




End Sub
```

Could it be because of the way I am referencing the `ActiveCell`?

Comment: It may be that the `.Find(…)` method in the preceding line is not finding anything. In that case, `nameRange` will be set to `Nothing`. You could add some code to test for/handle that.

Comment: Nope, it's most probably because your `.Find` method didn't find a result and return a `Nothing` and so, you've got your error! Add this line right before your `Set nameRange`, `MsgBox membership.Range("A:A").Find("user -name") Is Nothing`, if it displays `True` the find method didn't find anything, if it's `False` the problem is somewhere else! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a subsequent `Find` operation in the code that specifies only to look at the whole cell. This setting will persist so you probably just need to specify not to look at the whole cell in the first `Find` call:

```
Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").Find(What:="user -name", Lookat:=xlpart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does "user -name" exist the second time you run it?

```
 Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").Find("user -name")
    nameRow = nameRange.Row
    fullNameString = membership.Cells(nameRow, "A").Value
```

Check that nameRange returns a reference, and (I think), FIND remembers the last time it was used, so may be looking at cells below the previous FIND (see code below):

```
Dim nameRange As Range

Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").Find( _
    What:="user -name", _
    After:=membership.Range("A1"), _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not nameRange Is Nothing Then
    'Do stuff if namerange found.
End If
```

Wouldn't this line return the same value as nameRange?

```
fullNameString = membership.Cells(nameRow, "A").Value
```

You're telling it to return the value in column A on the nameRow row, while nameRange is returning a reference to that same cell so can just pull back the Value of that?